# How to convert one request param into several request params in Spring before calling a controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

The client sends some data in one request param like:

```
example.com/test?myparam=some123data
```

I would like to convert `myparam` into several other params and call a necessary controller with such parameters. Like this one:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public @ResponseBody MyObject test(
    @RequestParam(value = "prefix") String prefix, // some
    @RequestParam(value = "number") int number, // 123
    @RequestParam(value = "suffix") String suffix)  //data
{ ... }
```

It is possible to put some custom converter for such situation?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure if it can be made wit request params. Instead, you could use path variables with regular expressions in the following way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{prefix:[a-z]+}{number:[0-9]+}{suffix:[a-z]+}")
public @ResponseBody MyObject test(
    @PathVariable(value = "prefix") String prefix, // some
    @PathVariable(value = "number") int number, // 123
    @PathVariable(value = "suffix") String suffix)  //data
{ ... }
```

In this case your request URL will look like this:

```
example.com/test/some123data
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Your method solves the problem above but I will leave the question open because I need a little bit more logic here than regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement your own argument resolver, [here an example](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-creating-a-custom-handlermethodargumentresolver/)